# How can we use R to loop over the different lines contained in the text file and convert it to a list?

Tags: r

My Python homework:

1. Use the open() built-in function to open the file named dialog.txt and assign it to a variable named file.
2. Using the list() function assign all lines contained in a file to a variable named lines.
3. Close the file using the close() method.

My Python answer that is working:

```
file = open("dialog.txt", "r")
lines = list(file)
file.close()
```

***How can we do the same with R?***

This is the list that the Python code produces.

[image]

Can you help with me with R? I am curious. It is not part of the homework. I do not know what to do after this:

```
# Read a txt file, named "dialog.txt"
file <- read.delim("dialog.txt")
```

Comment: Perhaps `readLines` is what you are looking for? Based on what your expected output should look like. What exactly do you want to get in R?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just want the same result that I am getting with Python. A list identical to the one that is in the picture.

Comment: Yes, as @MartinGal said `lines <- readLines(path)` is it.

Comment: Can you publish a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution:

```
lines <- as.list(readLines(path))
```

To your question:

```
as.list(as.character(unlist(read.delim("test.csv", head=FALSE, sep="\n"))))
```

would also give lines.

But all outputs are without "\n" at the end.

I would highly recommend, however, to leave the `as.list()` away. R is not Python.

For R you have to follow: Whenever you can use a vector, you should.
Because the performance of vectors is 10 if not 100x better than that of lists (whenever the number of element gets very high).

Comment: Thank you for your help! When I use typeof(as.character(unlist(read.delim("test.csv", head=FALSE, sep="\n")))), your answer produces a character vector, not a list. The answer requires a list. Each line needs to be a different element of the list.

Comment: Also, when I use typeof(lines <- readLines(path)) produces a list, but all the lines are in the first element. The answer requires that each line is a different element.

Comment: No, actually `readLines(path)` generates a character Vector.

Comment: You can make a character vector as a list: `as.list(you_character_vector)`. But, coming from Python to R, you think R's List is as good as Python's. But that is not true. In R you should always prefer Vectors over Lists. Vectors are lists whose elements have the same type. While lists in R can contain - like Python lists - elements of different/all kind of types. However, in R, this goes with a big performance penalty. In R, you should avoid lists whenever possible. Vectors in R in contrast are super performant - faster than python lists.

Comment: You are right! Sorry! Thank you for the correction! However, the answer requires a list. Each line should be a different element of the list.

Comment: When you are programming in R, you have to think differently than in Python. e.g. in R you hardly use for-loops. You have to use rather higher order functions like the apply-family functions, or Map, Reduce ...

Comment: I corrected in the answer. But just telling you, the `readLines` function in R returns a vector because this is the best, most convenient form to handle the output. Lists in R are very slow.

Comment: Thank you! Your advice as.list(you_character_vector) solves the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your teachings! Thank you so much!

Comment: My advice is leave the `as.list()` away. Because the string functions are all vectorized - so they expect a vector of strings. Imagine, you want to replace in all the line strings all "r" by an "R". you do like this: `lines <- readLines(path)` and then: `gsub("r", "R", lines)` - no looping necessary because you can use natural, inbuilt vectorization of R vectors. But with the `lines <- as.list(readLines(path))` you have to do: `lapply(lines, function(line) gsub("r", "R", line))` And in all following functions too. In addition, this is at least 10 if not 100x slower than the vectorized version.

Comment: So you are working against the language this way.

Comment: I just wanted to use the opportunity to learn more about lists in R. I saw one a NASA file. They used a big list. I understand your teaching that lists are not best, but sometimes people use them, and you need to know how to get the information from there.